# Android TV Emulator Network Off

Tags: android, android-tv

Does android tv emulator support internet connection? Although i get all the permissions, my app does not connect to the internet? What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you working on Android M TV emulator? It does seem to have problem with internet access

Comment: Yeah i am working on api 23. I am sure i have internet connection. But emulator can not connect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974407/android-tv-emulator-no-internet-access

Comment: Thanks for the link and yeah switch to api 22 works but it is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Update the emulator to new version will solve the problem.

Ex. if you are using lollipop emulator then update it to marshmallow